# Mean values from multiple csv to data frame

Tags: r, csv

After having searched for help in different threads on this topic, I still have not become wiser. Therefore: Here comes another question on looping through multiple data files...

OK. I have multiple CSV files in one folder containing 5 columns of data. The filenames are as follows:

Moist yyyymmdd hh_mm_ss.csv

I would like to create a script that reads processes the CSV-files one by one doing the following steps:

1) load file
2) check number of rows and exclude file if less than 3 registrations
3) calculate mean value of all measurements (=rows) for column 2
4) calculate mean value of all measurements (=rows) for column 4
5) output the filename timestamp, mean column 2 and mean column 4 to a data frame,

I have written the following function

```
moist.each.mean <- function() {
  library("tcltk")
  directory <- tk_choose.dir("","Choose folder for Humidity data files")
  setwd(directory)
  filelist <- list.files(path = directory)
  filetitles <- regmatches(filelist, regexpr("[0-9].*[0-9]", filelist))
  mdf <- data.frame(timestamp=character(), humidity=numeric(), temp=numeric())

  for(i in 1:length(filelist)){
    file.in[[i]] <- read.csv(filelist[i], header=F)
    if (nrow(file.in[[i]]<3)){
      print("discard")
    } else {
      newrow <- c(filetitles[[i]], round(mean(file.in[[i]]$V2),1), round(mean(file.in[[i]]$V4),1))
      mdf <- rbind(mdf, newrow)
    }
  } 
  names(mdf) <- c("timestamp", "humidity", "temp")
}
```

but i keep getting an error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(V1 = c(10519949L,  : 
  replacement has 18 rows, data has 17
```

Any ideas?

Thx, kruemelprinz

Comment: where is `file.in` defined?

Comment: I do not know how to define it, unfortunately. I have already struggled quite much to come this far... file.in is meant to be the temporary object for loading in a certain csv until it is overwritten by the next file that is processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd also suggest to use (l)apply... Here's my take:

```
getMeans <- function(fpath,runfct,
                 target_cols = c(2),
                 sep=",",
                 dec=".",
                 header = T,
                 min_obs_threshold = 3){
```

f <- list.files(fpath)
    fcsv <- f[grepl("\.csv",f)]

```
fcsv <- paste0(fpath,fcsv)

csv_list <- lapply(fcsv,read.table,sep = sep,
                 dec = dec, header = header)

csv_rows <- sapply(csv_list,nrow)

rel_csv_list <- csv_list[!(csv_rows < min_obs_threshold)]

lapply(rel_csv_list,function(x) colMeans(x[,target_cols]))


 }
```

Also with that kind of error message, the debugger might be very helpful. 
Just run `debug(moist.each.mean)` and execute the function stepwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach. Use `lapply` to read each csv file, exclude it if necessary, otherwise create a summary. This gives you a list where each element is a data frame summary. Then use `rbind` to create the final summary data frame.

Without a sample of your data, I can't be sure the code below exactly matches your problem, but hopefully it will be enough to get you where you want to go.

```
# Get vector of filenames to read
filelist=list.files(path=directory, pattern="csv")

# Read all the csv files into a list and create summaries
df.list = lapply(filelist, function(f) {

  file.in = read.csv(f, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  # Set to empty data frame if file has less than 3 rows of data
  if (nrow(file.in) < 3) {

    print(paste("Discard", f))

  # Otherwise, capture file timestamp and summarise data frame  
  } else {

    data.frame(timestamp=substr(f, 7, 22), 
               humidity=round(mean(file.in$V2),1), 
               temp=round(mean(file.in$V4),1))
  }
})

# Bind list into final summary data frame (excluding the list elements
# that don't contain a data frame because they didn't have enough rows
# to be included in the summary)
result = do.call(rbind, df.list[sapply(df.list, is.data.frame)])
```

One issue with your original code is that you create a vector of summary results rather than a data frame of results:

`c(filetitles[[i]], round(mean(file.in[[i]]$V2),1), round(mean(file.in[[i]]$V4),1))` is a vector with three elements. What you actually want is a data frame with three columns:

```
data.frame(timestamp=filetitles[[i]], 
           humidity=round(mean(file.in[[i]]$V2),1), 
           temp=round(mean(file.in[[i]]$V4),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions using `lapply`. This is definitely of value as it saves a whole lot of code as well! Meanwhile, I managed to fix my original code as well:

```
library("tcltk")
# directory: path to csv files
directory <-
  tk_choose.dir("","Choose folder for Humidity data files")
setwd(directory)
filelist <- list.files(path = directory)
filetitles <-
  regmatches(filelist, regexpr("[0-9].*[0-9]", filelist))
mdf <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(filelist)) {
  file.in <- read.csv(filelist[i], header = F, skipNul = T)
  if (nrow(file.in) < 3) {
    print("discard")
  } else {
    newrow <-
      matrix(
        c(filetitles[[i]], round(mean(file.in$V2, na.rm=T),1), round(mean(file.in$V4, na.rm=T),1)), nrow = 1, ncol =
          3, byrow = T
      )
    mdf <-  rbind(mdf, newrow)
  }
}

names(mdf) <- c("timestamp", "humidity", "temp")
```

Only I did not get it to work as a function because then I would only have one row in `mdf` containing the last file data. Somehow it did not add rows but overwrite row 1 with each iteration. But using it without a function wrapper worked fine...